# Redirect dynamic url with single non-numeric parameter to static extension-less root level url with name consisting of parameter value text

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess

I have an `.htaccess` that allows me to use `.php` files urls without extension:

```css
    # if not a directory and .php file is present then add .php extension
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
    RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

I am trying to create a controller `page.php` file that will allow me to generate multiple dynamic pages depending on the parameter value, such as:

https://www.example.com/page.php?pid=some-page-slug-1

https://www.example.com/page.php?pid=some-page-slug-2

and so on.

I would like to turn the above dynamic links to static in the next fashion:

https://www.example.com/page.php?pid=some-page-slug-1

turns to:

https://www.example.com/some-page-slug-1

I've tried to modify some template I found on internet but its not working:

```css
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ page.php?pid=$1
```

What is the correct markup to rewrite dynamic url with single non-numeric parameter to static extension-less root level url with name consisting of parameter value text in a SEO friendly way?

Comment: RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ page.php?pid=$1 is not working because https://www.example.com/some-page-slug-1 is not finishing with .php.

Comment: Do you still want the above rewrite rules? Are users able to access to pages of your website only from static links like this https://www.example.com/some-page-slug-1? Is there any other file that generate response to users except page.php?

Comment: @AmirMB Yes only the dynamic pages with `font.php` controller has to follow the new rule, all the existing pages such as http://example.com/some-page.php should be accessible via extension-less (http://example.com/some-page) urls as they were before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

# if not a directory and .php file is present then add .php extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

# singe parameter static URL handlinng
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ page.php?pid=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks, it works great for dynamic pages with `page.php` controller, but now all other regular static pages on visit sent to `page.php` controller as well... I just need dynamic pages with `page.php` controller in url redirected and all the regular static urls redirect to corresponding static `.php` pages as usual.

Comment: Nvm, after switching the order of the code blocks in your answer it is now works as a charm, you are amazing as always, anubhava! <3